# CodeIgniter: Connecting two mysql instances

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, sockets

I want to use two database instances in my CodeIgniter application. I have set up db1 and db2 in the application but it always uses the socket of the first database.

```
$this->db2 = $this->load->database('db2', TRUE);

Message: mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

but the second server runs on '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld2.sock'
I can not see where to tell it to use the second socket.

Please note that I still want to connect to the first database too, I need to merge two replications, so setting defalut socket in php.ini is not an option.

Comment: [After some very brief Googling](https://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/145901/)

Comment: I did all that, I select db2 as you see in my example call $this->db2 = $this->load->database('db2', TRUE); the problem is, that the second db runs on mysql2.sock and not mysql.sock

Comment: Does really NO ONE have an answer to this??

Answer (score 0):

You'll also need to edit your database config file to add the additional settings. Example:

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
..
..
..
$db['second_db']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
```

Comment: They both run on localhost, that's why there are two sockets mysql.sock and mysql2.sock

Comment: IT is okay if they both run on local host, just have the config for them BOTH. I would assume the db names are different.

Comment: Well I have both arrays, db1 and db2. Both servers have different ports and different sockets. But PHP still always tries to access mysql.sock and not mysql2.sock but I need both at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it was something CodeIgniter was missing, at least for mysqli driver: The socket parameter was always NULL in the driver code. With a modification of the code and the configuration array, it is possible to connect to any given socket for the server(s).

Add this to your config

`'socket'   => '/tmp/mysql.sock', // if no socked uses set it to NULL`

And change this in your /system/database/mysqli/mysqli_driver.php

```
return $mysqli->real_connect($hostname, $this->username, $this->password, $this->database, $port, $this->socket, $client_flags)
```

But keep in mind that editing core files could conflict with framework updates, causing errors in your database implementation.

http://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-486.html